# What is the tricky point of saying "float one's boat"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

What was going on in [this discussion](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/11360848) about the phrase “I don’t bite"?

The translation:
[image]

The comments:
[image]
<sub>If you happen to be on a mobile device, the conversation runs like this:</sub>

> <sup>**Translation**: I don't bite.</sup>
>   <sub>**Response 1**: Unless that's what floats your boat.</sub>
>   <sub>**Response 2**: But Luis Suarez does</sub>
>   <sub>**Response 3**: This could go in the flirting lesson</sub>

---

Face palm. It seems that it relates to Luis Suarez according to the discussion and sexual attraction according to [this Twitter](https://twitter.com/blandy_son/status/775652861296406528).

> Brendan Rodgers "Luis Suarez is one of the most beautiful men you can
>   come across" Whatever floats your boat lad... #SkySports #Celtic

Could anyone please explain that a little bit?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add to your question the word or usage that you don't understand. If you don't do that, your question may attract close votes. It's good to include a link to the source of text with which you are concerned, but you should always include the text itself in your question. (See [this link.](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/whatever_floats_your_boat))

Comment: @P.E.Dant Following your warnings I have added the context by uploading a screenshot of the discussion. Does that need further edition?

Comment: Text is preferable to giant horsey graphics which render very poorly on a mobile device. There may be those who enjoy reaing 5 point type, but I suspect that they are in the minority. Why not just copy the text instead? I would rather that my comment is interpreted as advice than as a "warning." It certainly was intended as such. The point is that, rather than having to follow a bunch of links, and then return to your question, many readers would rather have all the elements of the question before them in one place. I should think this is obvious, but I'm always willing to be corrected.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I am afraid of losing something interesting in the discussion, then I just provide the picture of it.

Comment: Lerner - I think that PE Dant’s initial concern was a valid one – we don’t want the discussion to disappear – but I also think in this case the screen shot works just fine.  I did add the “I don’t bite” part to the text of your question so that it might show up in a future search.

Comment: @J.R. Many readers access our site with a mobile. You need an electron microscope to read the above interchange on a mobile. Have you had a look? In 2017, I don't think this is a trifle.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Good grief. You harp too much and fix too little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s an interesting discussion, because people are responding to the original phrase in various literal and figurative ways.

As is said in the original conversation, “I don’t bite” usually means:

- "I won't hurt you/I don't mean any harm”, or
- "I am not going to hurt you, dont be shy...”

The phrase “[float your boat](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning%20of%20float%20your%20boat)” means “makes you happy” or “turns you on,” so, in this context, I presume “Unless it floats your boat” means, “Unless it would turn you on if I nipped at your skin while we were making out”. It’s meant to be playfully flirtatious, in the same way one might say, “I don’t bite – unless you’re into that sort of thing.”

The Luis Suarez reference is due to the fact that the famous footballer has been known for [biting opponents on the field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Su%C3%A1rez_controversies). One could have quipped “Unless you’re [Mike Tyson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evander_Holyfield_vs._Mike_Tyson_II),” but that would have been a more dated reference.

So, what’s going on in that discussion? Insofar as I can tell, the two remarks are pretty much unrelated, except that they are both “punch lines” that can follow “I don’t bite,” if you think of biting in the literal sense rather than in the figurative sense that the speaker was likely intending.

---

As for that response at the end to Brendan Rodgers, Brendan is saying that he thinks the soccer player is remarkably attractive, and the commenter is implying that he (being male) doesn’t really evaluate men based on their attractiveness – but if Brendan wants to, well, that’s really up to Brendan. (It’s intended to be a playful, lighthearted and humorous jab.)

Comment: If possible could you please further explain why "float your boat" means "makes you happy"? I mean the etymology.

Comment: @Lerner See **[this link.](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/whatever_floats_your_boat)**

Comment: @P.E.Dant Methinks there should exist a story in history about that. Maybe. :)

Comment: @Lerner When a boat is beached, and the tide comes in, the boat floats on the surface. The idiom partakes of this image: the rising tide is "whatever", and "your" pleasure or interest is the boat. The idiom does not express a particularly complicated simile.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - It’s not particularly complicated, but it’s not exactly straightforward, either. I can see why this might be confusing for a learner.